# Am I right with my derivation of the dual of this linear program?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

\begin{align*}
  \min_{x_1,x_2} \quad - 4x_1 & + 2x_2 \\
  \text{subject to} \quad   - x_1 & + x_2 \geq 2 \\
         x_1 & - x_2 \geq 1 \\
         & x_1,x_2 \geq 0
  \end{align*}

\begin{align*}\text{Introducing four slack variables, $a,b,c,d\geq 0$}\\
L(x_1,x_2,a,b,c,d)=-4x_1+2x_2+a(2+x_1-x_2)+b(1+x_2-x_1)+cx_1-dx_2\\
=2a+b+x_1(-4+a-b+c)+x_2(2-a+b-d)\\
\max_{a,b,c,d}\min_{x_1,x_2}(2a+b+x_1(-4+a-b+c)+x_2(2-a+b-d))\\
\text{Since $x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0$}\\
a-b+c \geq 4\\
a-b+d \leq 2\\
\end{align*}

So finally we have,
\begin{align*}
\max_{a,b,c,d} \quad 2a+b \\
\text{subject to} \quad   a-b+c\geq4\\
a-b+d \leq 2 \\
a,b,c,d \geq 0 \\
\end{align*}

If it is right, where else should I add to the derivation process in order to make it more formal?

Comment: a,b,c,d are dual variables, not slacks; the derivation is wrong unfortunately, you have to either treat x,y as unconstrained and add c,d; or you treat x,y as nonnegative variables and not add c,d.

Comment: @LinAlg I realized that later! Thank you!